# How to make a color bar using three columns?

Tags: r, plot, colorbar

I have a table like following:

```
ID    type  group
A3EP    1    M
A3MA    2    M
A459    3    M
A3I1    5    M
A9D2    7    M
A3M9    4    M
A7XP    6    M
A4ZP    8    M
```

I want to make a color bar like following: Red color represents "group" and below that each color represents "type" and below that I want the "ID" names.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799468

Answer (score 2):

```
mypalette <- rainbow(8)
barplot(rep(0.5,8), width=1, space=0, col=mypalette, axes=F)
text(df$type-.5, .2, df$ID,  srt=90)

rect(0, .4, 8, .5, col="red")
text(4, .45, "M")
```

[image]

Input data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 3L, 7L, 6L
), .Label = c("A3EP", "A3I1", "A3M9", "A3MA", "A459", "A4ZP", 
"A7XP", "A9D2"), class = "factor"), type = 1:8, group = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "M")), .Names = 
c("ID", 
"type", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This looks fine. Could you also tell me what I need to do for the following one. ID    type  group
A3EP    1    M
A3MA    2    M
A459    3    M
A3I1    1    N
A9D2    3   N
A3M9    2   N
A7XP    3   O
A4ZP    2   O

Comment: Following what?

Comment: If I have different groups like "M","N","O". Each group should have a color.

Comment: And I just gave an example data here. I have a table with 1000 ID's

Comment: Did you get what I asked for?

Comment: Yes, but it's a totally different question and I wouldn't advise you to use base plot to do this. You should edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: Hi Adam...As you said I made a new question for my problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43799468/how-to-generate-a-color-plot-out-of-three-columns-from-a-data-frame-in-r) But nothing worked out yet. Could you please help me?